# Database model for individual users seeing notice

Tags: mysql, database, model

I am looking for the best solution for the way the mySQL db should be set up for my app.

My app works like a noticeboard with two sections, "New Notices" and "Seen Notices".

Now when a user has viewed a notice, they click a button and it moves from New to Seen. But ONLY for this person.

Each person will have all of the notices viewable - but not necessarily in the same sections - as users will view them at different times and check them off as seen at different times.

My guess is having one table "Notices" for all notices, and a seperate table called "Seen" with the rows "UserID" and "noticeID". This means that for each notice it will need to consult the "Seen" table to find out if it should be shown or not. Is this ideal or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Having a table with NoticeID and UserID is correct, I'd also add viewed date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 tables

1. Users
2. Notices
3. SeenNotices(maybe not the best name)

In the SeenNotices table have three columns UserID, NoticesID, HaveSeen. The have HaveSeen column will tell you if the user has seen it.

Comment: Hi hbrock, Why you need "HaveSeen" column in SeenNotices table? As I understand this table will only have the IDs of those notices that have been viewed by user. Please let me know if I am mistaken.

Comment: It is just a bool value to set it to true. By doing this you can have one table to find both seen and unseen notices

Answer (score 0):

The way you are thinking should work, although over time you'll end up with a very big 'Seen' table, which is not scalable. An easy alternative is to use 'Unseen' table instead. This way the table gets smaller as people view the notice and you can also delete very old entries (old notices may no longer relevant so doesn't matter if they are not shown as Unseen to user).

Using the 'unseen' table your query will look like this:

```
SELECT n.notice_id, n.notice_msg, IF(u.user_id, 'new', 'seen') AS status
FROM notice n
LEFT JOIN unseen u ON (u.user_id = $user_id AND n.notice_id = u.notice_id)
WHERE user_id = $user_id;
```

Comment: Would that not mean for every notice that is created, it is created for every single user and added to the unseen table?

Comment: That's right. I'm assuming the extra bottleneck in the notice creation does not matter much or the scalability benefits outweigh it.